# Azure DevOps - Restrict Work Item so only Discussion field editable

Tags: azure-devops, permissions

Dees anybody know if it is possible in Azure Dev Ops to create a rule or define permissions so that all the fields in a work item are ready only except the Discussion fields for a specific user or group?

Thanks